# How do I assert against objects with spies in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, sinon, cypress

I am using Cypress spies to test client-side analytics.

My intent in this test is to confirm that `identify` has been called like so:

`identify('myemail@email.com', { groupId: 1002, groupName: "myGroup", someProp: 1, anotherProp: 2 })`

I hook the spies into emitter events on a global `analytics` object in `window:before:load` (note the `while` loop is to deal with delays in the library loading):

```
Cypress.on("window:before:load", async (win: Window) => {

  const sleep = (n = 1) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, n));
  let set = false;
  while (set === false) {
    if (win["analytics"]) {
      set = true;
      const a = win["analytics"];
      const pageSpy = cy.spy().as("page");
      const idSpy = cy.spy().as("identify");
      a.on("page", pageSpy);
      a.on("identify", idSpy);

    } else {
       // default sleep of 1ms. this is b/c there's a super tight
       // window from analytics init and the calls I'm looking to
       // track (~25ms)
      await sleep();
      continue;
    }
  }
});
```

The intent here is that every time a `page` or `identify` method is called, the spy is called with the args from the `page` / `identify` call.

Then, in my test:

```
 it("calls identify on page load", () => {
    const idProps = {
      groupId: 1002,
      groupName: "myGroup",
      someProp: 1,
      anotherProp: 2
    };

    cy.visit("https://mypage.com");

    cy.get("@identify").should(
      "be.calledWith",
      "myemail@email.com"
    ).and("be.calledWith",idProps);
  });
```

The first assertion passes (`"be.calledWith", "myemail@email.com"`).

The second assertion, however, fails:

```
Command:  get
cypress_runner.js:141344 Alias:    @identify
cypress_runner.js:141344 Yielded:  ƒ identify
cypress_runner.js:141344 Error:    CypressError: Timed out retrying: expected identify to have been called with arguments Object{4}

    The following calls were made:

    identify("myemail@email.com", Object{4}, undefined) at o.proxy (https://exmaple.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:45839:22)
```

I have tried using `sinon.match`, but that [isn't supported in Cypress' version of sinon](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1328).

I also tried extracting the raw calls / args (ie `spy.getCalls()`), but this doesn't seem to be supported when accessing the spy via an alias (i.e. `cy.get('@identify')`).

So: is there any way to deep match the args passed to a cypress spy?

Comment: The spy construction looks a little non-standard - I would have thought cy.spy(a, 'identify').as('identify').

Comment: Also the while loop might be replaced with `cy.wrap(win).its('analytics')`. Should wait 5s for the property to appear, extendible with options on `its()`.

Comment: @eric99 the non-standard spies are b/c I was trying to hook them into Segment's event emitter as opposed to wrapping the method itself in a spy. The way you mentioned works as well, so long as the wrap happens before analytics snippet loads. That race condition is the reason for the while loop FWIW.

Answer (score 11):

I've solved the problem in the OP title. Wrapping the analytics method in a spy was another problem, but I've updated the snippet in OP to reflect how I fixed that (i.e., changing sleep interval to 1ms).

You can assert on the object in a spy call's args using the callback signature of `cy.should`:

```
 const idProps = {
      groupId: 1002,
      groupName: "myGroup",
      someProp: 1,
      anotherProp: 2
    };

cy.get("@identify").should(a => {
      expect(a).to.be.calledWith("myemail@email.com");
      // pardon the property index-ref style, using typescript and i'm lazy
      const spy = a["getCalls"](); 
      const { args } = spy[0];
      expect(args[1]).to.deep.equal(idProps);
    });
```

Comment: I've been trying to figure out how to get a spy from a stub for an hour now... thanks!